# How can I get the user's AD name when using SQL Auth in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to monitor which people connect to my database.
Most of the users connect to SQL Server with an application user like `crm_xxx`.

I want to know which person is behind this `crm_xxx`, so I want to know what's his user login name to the windows.

The question is how do I find this data?

I tried the following : `system_user`, `suser_sname`, `suser_name`.

All of them returned my login name to the windows instead of returning the name of the actual login name of the user who connected with `crm_xxx`.

thanks in advance

Comment: So you are using a SQL login and want to know the user's AD login? I don't think that is possible because SQL Server doesn't have that information to give you with that authentication scheme. Are the users connecting directly or via an app?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. most the users i'm talking about is connecting via an app.

Comment: Do you have the ability to control the connection string used by the app to connect to the DB. I have an idea for you if so.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. SQL Server doesn't have this information when you connect using a SQL login

Comment: before deleting my answer, isn't there any link to get from a processid to a query that get's executed?

Comment: @Lieven: there could be some fancy way via CLR, but SQL Server would get this info from the NT logon token. This isn't sent with a SQL login

Comment: gbn, so from where are the values of system_user, suser_sname, suser_name returned in this case? - they are not null but actually contains my login name to windows..

Comment: @user1171387: you aren't using a SQL login then

Comment: @gnb - i add a record each time someone enters the DB. ORIGINAL_LOGIN return me the name of the sql login - CRM_XXX. system_user, suser_sname, suser_name returns me wrong answer of my login although i have never logged with CRM_XXX...

Comment: *sigh*. suser_sname reflects the current login credentials. if you see "foo\bar" then it is windows auth. If you see "crm_bar" is is a SQL login. To get ORIGINAL_LOGIN different, then someone ran EXECUTE AS